# Python | tkinter: What does tkinter.END do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Learning python through a book, and tkinter.END is used in a block of code without being explained

```
import tkinter

def count(text, out_data):
    """ Update out_data with the total number of As, Ts, Cs, and Gs found in text.""" 

    data = text.get('0.0', **tkinter.END**)
    counts = {}
    for char in 'ATCG':
        counts[char] = data.count(char)
    out_data.set('Num As: {0} Num Ts: {1} Num Cs: {2} Num Gs: {3}'.format(
        counts['A'], counts['T'], counts['C'], counts['G']))
...
```

I've looked online, and I only run across examples of it, never mentioning it's function.
I tried `help(tkinter)` in a shell and got `END = 'end'` which wasn't very useful.
If more code is required, just let me know. Didn't want to post the entire code making you pointlessly read more for no reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't "do" anything. It is a constant, the literal string `"end"`. In this context it represents the point immediately after the last character entered by the user. The function `get` on a text widget requires two values: a starting position and an ending position.

Note: in the line `text.get('0.0', tkinter.END)`, `'0.0'` is invalid (though, tkinter graciously accepts it, and treats it the same as `'1.0'`). Text indexes are of the form *line.character*. Lines start counting at 1, characters start at zero. So, the first character is `'1.0'`, not `'0.0'`.

Comment: I just want to verify. So '1.0' is used as a starting point, and then END is used to set the stopping point? Almost like selecting the text, then setting it to data?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a constant.

The Python tkinter library is a wrapper around tk, so you'll want to reference the source documentation, which can be found at: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#basics.

For your question, see the section on Retrieving the Text. In their Python example, they don't even use the constant:

```
thetext = text.get('1.0', 'end')
```